# Can we train a pre-trained model with new data using tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, classification, conv-neural-network

I have a trained model which can classify a cat or a dog as an h5 file named

> catsvsdogs.h5

Now I want to add another animal in the list. Say I want to classify cat/dog/tiger using that model and I don't want to redo the training process of cat and dog, instead I want to feed the tiger data set in my neural network and then it will classify dog or cat or tiger with that same file.
Is it possible to do so? If yes, how?

Comment: Down-voted as question is lacking some details showing and attempt to find an answer, eg: how model is loaded back from `*.h5` file

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately , this is not possible. You can of course train a model for `tiger` class but you would also need the `dogs & cats` data for making the model to classify between these 3 classes.

If you load this (`catsvsdogs.h5`) pre-trained model for training on only `tiger` class you would have to set output layer with `1` class, so at the time of prediction it will only predict if it is tiger or not.

Retraining a trained model on only new class is still a research question.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible as your model is structured in a way that it can assign one of two classes to an image, you have to change the outermost layer and retrain it.